# setting monitor_slug="slug-name" in @sentry_sdk.crons.monitor() doesn't work

Tags: django-celery, sentry

When using sentry to monitor my django-celery cron job.

I add a Monitor to sentry.io/corns
[image]

Then use @sentry_sdk.crons.monitor to decorate my task

```py
@shared_task
@sentry_sdk.crons.monitor(monitor_slug="check-server-alive-cron-job")
def is_server_alive(server_url):
    ....
```

The problem is:
When the task run it create a new monitor name "test" and successfully capture signals
while monitor `check-server-alive-cron-job` captures nothing.

pkg installed:

```
celery==5.2.7
django-celery-results==2.4.0
django-celery-beat==2.5.0
redis==4.5.4
sentry-sdk==1.21.0
```

Answer (score 0):

After one days research, solved it

**mark some key points here:**

1. after setting up django with celery, init `sentry_sdk` in settings

```py
    sentry_sdk.init(dsn=settings.SENTRY_DSN,
                    integrations=[CeleryIntegration(monitor_beat_tasks=True)],    # <<<< important
                    environment="ck-test",
                    )
```

2. run celery worker with `-E`

```bash
celery -A proj worker -E --autoscale=10,20 --beat --scheduler django -l info
```

because

```bash
$celery worker --help
  ....
  -E, --task-events, --events     Send task-related events that can be
                                  captured by monitors like celery events,
                                  celerymon, and others.
```

3. change my task name to `Check Server Alive Cron Job`

because [refs:](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/guides/celery/)

```
Sentry Python SDK will set the transaction on the event to the task name, and it will improve the grouping for global Celery errors such as timeouts.
```

so in django admin:
[image]

Then finally the monitor get checkins
[image]